# connection error when trying to connect postgres database to vscode

Tags: postgresql, visual-studio-code, heroku, database-connection

I have an issue when I try to establish a connection with my Heroku database through the *PostgreSQL* extension in VScode. I type in all the credentials information and get an error saying **"Input is not valid base64-encoded data."**

Historically it worked like a charm. Seemingly out of nowhere (where nothing comes from, but I really can't establish any change in my setup) all my connections were gone from VScode and I cannot reestablish them. I uninstalled and reinstalled the plugin without any luck. I can connect to the database from my command line sooo - does anyone know what's up and down here?

Also I'm not a technical expert so pls bear with me.

and by the way, there seems to be too large postgresql extensions for vscode, I can get through with the Microsoft one, but I can only save results as excel though it does promiss me json. Solving that little issue would also work for me :-/

Thank you
/Kira

Comment: Seems like some update in vscode resulted in this; details are [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/147515#:~:text=The%20error%20being%20received%20is%3A%20%22Input%20is%20not,to%20securely%20store%20credentials%20used%20by%20my%20extension.?msclkid=d3b10ed3c79811ec8463d214de31c3ce)

Comment: Ahh - so my best bet is probably to wait a little and se. It looks like a fix will be part of an update released this month (May '22).